# Besides the enteric nervous system are there other clusters of nerves that might also be called "brains"?

Tags: brain, nervous-systems

I have read that the enteric nervous system might be called a separate brain. I read further that there might be 3 or even 6 human nervous systems. Could any of these be considered a brain in the same sense as the enteric nervous system and what are the criteria for classifying some cluster of nerves (neurons?) in the body as a "brain"?

Comment: Welcome. Can you add links to the full-texts of your sources?

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19702/7604

Comment: the heart has 40k neurons so maybe that, cuz vascular system is p important to computation